# How to check that whether words of arrayList are available in EditText in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-edittext, words

I have ArrayList of certain Words :

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
words.add("this");
words.add("that");
```

And i have EditText :

```
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(userName);
```

Now I want to check that whether words of arrayList are available in name(EditText) :

```
Boolean WordsAvailable;
WordsAvailable = checkWords(name.getText().toString());
```

Now I want to make function to check whether words of arrayList are available or not in EditText as below:

```
public Boolean checkWords(String checkString)
{
    for(int i=0;i<words.size();i++)
    {
         // Here i want to check that whether words of arrayList are available in EditText
         If ( word is available )
        {
         return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

How can i check this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(checkString.contains(words.get(i)))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use String.contains(), like so:

```
public Boolean checkWords(String checkString)
{
    for(String word : words)
    {
         if (checkString.contains(word))
         {
             return YES;
         }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:

```
if(checkString.equals(words.get(i))){


         return YES;
        }

}
```